# Please reorder the Help Center links to emphasize what should be asked rather than what not to ask

Tags: support, design, help-center

The three pinned posts on the "asking" section of the [Help Center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help) are:

> - What types of questions should I avoid asking?
> - What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?
> - What topics can I ask about here?

In that order.

I think that on *most* sites, the order is reversed - this seems to be something that changed in the past but I've seen them changed after the fact (cf the same request on [Arts and Crafts](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/can-we-please-change-the-order-of-the-pinned-topics-in-our-help-center)).

Could we please have them in the following order:

- What topics can I ask about here?
- What types of questions should I avoid asking?
- What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?

Answer (score 5):

If you edit the "What topics can I ask about here?" topic, it'll jump to the top.

So... Edit the "What topics can I ask about here?" topic.

Comment: Ah. See... Pops didn't tell us that the last time. I figured it had to do with building that page and it wouldn't ever change unless you all did something about it.

Comment: Well, we can screw with the pinning to adjust the order, but that's probably unnecessary given the order will be what you want as soon as you start filling in the on-topic page.

Comment: I don't think that this actually works. I just edited the page and the links are still in the wrong order.

Comment: Hmm... Well, at some point I'll have to figure out why that didn't work. But for now, I just screwed with the pinning.

Comment: Thanks. :) I guessed that it might be the case when I answered a MSE question about Musicals and noticed that the Literature help page wasn't reordered but did have custom text. I tested it here and then pinged you.